# Highcharts Column Chart Not Displaying Dynamic Values

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

Hi I need to create one dynamic column chart. But i am not able to put my values to the data field of value how can i do that

```
 function getusercategorygraph()
{
$.getJSON('config/alumniusermodes.php',function(data){ 
        // Create a new array
        var finaldata = [];
        var chart;

        // Perform your operations
        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
            // Create a new hash
            var currentItem = {}

            // Create the proper values in your hash
            $.each(value, function( index, value ) {
                currentItem[index] = value;  

            });            
                finaldata += currentItem;

         });
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({        
            chart: {              
                renderTo : 'user-count',
                type: 'column',                    
            },
            title: {                                                
                text: 'Alumni Users By Category Analytics'
            },                                            
            xAxis: {
                color:'#0077CC',
                //type: 'category',
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Number of Alumni Members'
                }

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y} Members'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} Members</b><br/>'
            },

            series: [{
                name: "Alumni Type",
                colorByPoint: true,
                //data: [{ name : 'Standard',  y : 52, },{ name : 'Silver',  y : 24, },{ name : 'Gold',  y : 20, },{ name : 'Platinum',  y : 6, },]
                //data: [{ name : 'Standard',  y : 52, },{ name : 'Silver',  y : 24, },{ name : 'Gold',  y : 20, },{ name : 'Platinum',  y : 6, },]
                data : finaldata,
            }],
        }); 
    });
}
```

But the graph doesnt show anything. Whats wrong in this code. Please help.
this is the result from api that i got

```
[{"name":"Standard","y":"52"},{"name":"Silver","y":"24"},{"name":"Gold","y":"20"},{"name":"Platinum","y":"6"}]
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started, on line 18, change

```
finaldata += currentItem;
```

to

```
finaldata.push({
    name: currentItem.name,
    y: parseFloat(currentItem.y)
});
```

See [JSFilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx97txx1/1/).

Edit: Used suggestions by Sebastian in comments. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to view names(standard.silver gold planium in the x axis. How can we do that.
And also how to view
tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} Members</b><br/>'
            },
point.name in this

Comment: I fixed this demo, because there are lines which you don't need to use. Updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/jx97txx1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version keeping the highchart code inside $.getJSON callback function.

I added following PHP back-end code to get highchart sample data.

```
$data[] = array('name' => 'Standard', 'y'=> 52);
$data[] = array('name' => 'Silver', 'y'=> 24);
$data[] = array('name' => 'Gold', 'y'=> 20);
$data[] = array('name' => 'Platinum', 'y'=> 6);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

This data is nothing but giving me data to use in highchart. Following is the javascript call to get it functional.

```
getusercategorygraph();
function getusercategorygraph()
{
    $.getJSON('http://<mydomain>/getdata.php',function(data){
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo : 'container',
                type: 'column',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Alumni Users By Category Analytics'
            },
            xAxis: {
                color:'#0077CC',
                //type: 'category',
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Number of Alumni Members'
                }

            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y} Members'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
pointFormat:'<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>:<b>{point.y}Members</b><br/>'
            },

            series: [{
                name: "Alumni Type",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: data
            }],
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: if i do like that total error. Nothing is displaying. How can we do that. Final data balur how to force value outside getjson success side to chart data section

Comment: Did you try this? @KrishnakumarKU